# Is it still possible to get the Twitter cover on the top?

Tags: twitter

My profile has changed it's lay-out. There used to be option to have a big wide cover at the top like on the picture below, but now I have "Tweets, Following, Follows, Favorites, Lists" on the top-left and the cover more on the right.

[image]

You can see the cover is very wide and located at the top. I liked this better than the new profile page with the cover on the right and menu options on the left.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can’t. This is the new layout, that has been rolled out to all users starting December 12. ([Source](http://blog.twitter.com/2012/12/new-profiles-for-everyone.html).)